# Store subscription from custom Combine subscriber?

Tags: swift, subscription, combine

According to the swift combine documentation, the proper way to connect a subscriber to a publisher is with the publishers `subscribe<S>(S)` protocol extension method.  Then the publisher creates a subscription and passes that subscription on to the subscriber.  All's well and good so far.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to gain access to that subscription and retain it in the calling code.  How is `sink()` implemented such that it can return that subscription?  Unless I'm mistaken, the subscription is responsible for retaining its subscriber, which means I can't store a reference to the subscription in the subscriber.  And since Subscription isn't class bound, it can't be weak.

Comment: Interestingly, when I try to add a weak reference to a Subscription I get an error that it is "non-class-bound".  But Apple's own documentation says: "Subscriptions are class constrained because a Subscription has identity, defined by the moment in time a particular subscriber attached to a publisher".  I'm not sure what to make of that discrepancy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how `sink` *might* be implemented

```
import Combine
import Foundation

extension Publisher {
    func mockSink(
        receiveValue: @escaping (Output) -> Void,
        receiveCompletion: @escaping (Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) -> Void) -> AnyCancellable {

            var result : AnyCancellable!
            let anySubscriber = AnySubscriber(
                receiveSubscription: { subscription in
                    subscription.request(.unlimited)
                    result = AnyCancellable({subscription.cancel()})
                },
                receiveValue: { (value : Output) in receiveValue(value); return .unlimited},
                receiveCompletion: receiveCompletion)

            subscribe(anySubscriber)
            return result
        }
}

var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
["one", "two", "three"].publisher
    .mockSink(receiveValue: {debugPrint($0)}, receiveCompletion: {debugPrint($0)})
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

As you can see the ability to return an `AnyCancellable` arises from the magic of `AnySubscriber` which returns its subscription in a closure.  `AnySubscriber` is a handy tool to have when implementing custom `Publishers` and it may be helpful if you want to implement your own `Subscriber` type.  But basically a `Subscriber` only exposes the subscription if it is designed to.

Comment: Brilliant!  I hadn't considered AnySubscriber!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The cancellable retains the subscription (or possibly *is* the subscription. Remember Subscriptions are Cancellables.) So when you retain the Cancellable, you are retaining the subscription.

Comment: That's the opposite of what I have been reading, and doesn't make a ton of sense given that the subscription needs to be able to send a completion on deinit.  How could that ever happen if the subscriber is retaining the subscription?